# EMR PySpark "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'"

Tags: pyspark, pip, conda, amazon-emr, spacy

I've been unsuccessfully trying to install Spacy onto my EMR cluster to run a Pyspark job.
My Bootstrapping actions to EMR look something like this

```
pip install --upgrade pip

sudo conda install -c conda-forge spacy
sudo python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
sudo python3 -m spacy download en 

sudo python3 -m pip install -U spacy
sudo python3 -m pip install -U boto3
sudo python3 -m pip install -U pandas
sudo python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
sudo python3 -m spacy download en
```

As you see above i've been trying to install it via pip and conda both but none seem to work.
Suprisingly when I use a jupyter notebook and not try to submit my pyspark job as a step to EMR it works.

Comment: I see that you install the package for python3 and for conda. Can you check which version of python is being used by pyspark? It should be set in `./conf/spark-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem. Some of the things that could work:

1. Check the stdout, stderr files in EMR, on bootstrap actions. It's mentioned under the summary section of the cluster-Configuration details-LOG URI
2. Apparently, Spacy has Cython dependency and it's not downloaded automatically. Thus including the following commands helped:

```
    sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

    sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
    
    sudo python3 -m pip install wheel
    
    sudo python3 -m pip install -U Cython

    sudo python3 -m pip install -U spacy==2.3.5

    sudo python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Comment: What does the error log look like when dependency is not installed properly? I see in stdout.gz all few libraries with `processing` but not `succesfully installed mention`